# Simple problems with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have three questions:

#### 1)

I want to compute the following using MATLAB:

```
11^2 + 13^2 + 15^2 + ... + 109^2 + 111^2
```

I have tried using:

```
x = [11^2 13^2 15^2 ... 109^2 111^2]
z = cum(single(x))
```

but I got an error...

#### 2)

I want to display '2 sin/pix'... I tried:

```
tittle('2 sin/pix')
```

Can I represent the display without displaying it in figure?

#### 3)

The Fibonacci series is given as follow:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...
```

How can I write a script file to calculate and print out the n-th Fibonacci term for n>2, where n is input by the user.

This is what I've tried:

```
input('n: ')
z = cumsum(n)
fprintf('the series=%d')
```

but I received an error...

Comment: This is actually several different questions, maybe you should separate them?

Comment: Make seperate questions, please.

Answer (score 4):

1)

```
sum([11:2:111].^2)
```

2) Depending on whether you want a title or a text in a figure:

```
text(.5,.5,'2 sin\pix', 'interpreter','tex')
title('2 sin\pix', 'interpreter','tex')
```

BTW, the ASCII symbol of π is: 227 (Press and hold ALT and type 227 on Windows)

3) Take a look at this page:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/17/fibonacci-and-filter/

Comment: Actually, pi does not exist in ASCII or ISO-8859-1.  But it is U+03C0 in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

In the first subquestion, maybe you just mean `sum` instead of `cum` ?

I would do it like this:

```
x = [11:2:111]
sum(x .^ 2)
```

The first line is a range, giving a vector of every other number from 11 to 111, the second does a per-element squaring in that vector and sums it.

For the second question, I'm not sure what you really want to do.  How about:

```
disp('2 sin/pix')
```

Comment: actually i want to display pi as symbol 
may be like this : 2 sin\pix
but wat function should i use? disp, title or text?

Comment: @izzat: How to do that depends on where you want to display it.  `disp` writes to your matlab shell, and I don't think you can use tex there, but if your environment supports unicode, try simply `disp('2 sin πx')`.  If you want it somewhere in a diagram, try `text` or `title` as described by MR-123.

Answer (score 0):

To compute: 11^2+13^2+...+109^2+111^2, try:
    sum((11:2:111).^2)

To display '2 sin/pix'), the command is 'title' not 'tittle':
    title('2 sin/pix')

Is this homework?

Comment: i've tried with 

x=[11^2:2:111^2]
sum(x)

it gives different answer as yours...
which one is correct?

Comment: @izzat [11:2:111] .^ 2 gives the squer of every other number from 11 to 111.  [11^2:2:111^2] on the other hand, gives every other number from 121 to 12321.

Comment: Madsen's is correct.  What your code does is actually x = [121:2:12321]; sum(x);  <br> Which is not at all what you want.  Those parens matter.